# Need guidance on creating an SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am VERY new to SQL and I just started creating my own database in SQL Management Studio 2014 at home. So I am still learning the basics.
The database is called FitnessClub (a fictional company I made up).

In that database, I have **three** tables: Pupils, Sports and PupilsSports (I think you call it a junction table?) Please assume that I have sorted out the PK and FK in all the tables correctly.

I have decided to add 20 Pupils and 10 Sports. I have allocated the first 10 Pupils with the 10 sports consecutively which means that the remaining 10 Pupils have NOT been allocated a sport.

In my PupilsSports table, I have PupilID(PK) and SportID(PK) both relating to the respective column in the other two tables and this is where I have added the 10 Pupils with the 10 sports in a simple manner like this:

```
  +-----+-------+
  | P.ID | S.ID |
  +-----+-------+
  | 1   | 1     | 
  | 2   | 2     | 
  | 3   | 3     |
  | 4   | 4     |
  | 5   | 5     | 
  | 6   | 6     | 
  | 7   | 7     |
  | 8   | 8     |
  | 9   | 9     | 
  | 10  | 10    | 
  +-----+-------+
```

I would like to create an SQL query that I can run to find out the list of Pupils who have NOT been allocated to a sport? Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is easily possible.  If you are just learning SQL, you would better off following tutorials that are freely available on the internet, and maybe a book or two, rather than asking a question in a forum for every new technique that you want to learn.  This question is very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer join and a filter on null values should do the trick.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Pupils
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PupilsSports
    ON Pupils.ID = PupilsSports.PupilID
WHERE
  PupilsSports.SportID IS NULL
```

Basically an outer join would give you the complete superset of joining both tables, leaving values as `NULL` where no matching record was found.  So filtering on those `NULL` values in the `WHERE` clause should reduce the result set to include only those records where no matching joined record was found.

Or perhaps a sub-query approach instead:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Pupils
WHERE
  ID NOT IN (SELECT PupilID FROM PupilsSports)
```

There are a number of different ways to accomplish the task, I imagine.  What might be an interesting learning experience is to examine the query execution plan in SQL Management Studio for each approach and see how they differ and where any potential bottlenecks may be.

Comment: Thank you, David. As basic as my problem sounds, I had no idea about using the sub-query!

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin that cat... here's one that's relatively easy to understand:

```
SELECT * FROM Pupils WHERE PupilID NOT IN (SELECT PupilID FROM PupilsSports)
```

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to not simply write this query for you, I'll try to point you to what you need.  First, you need to `JOIN` these two tables together.  A `LEFT JOIN` will take all rows from the left-hand table, and only matching rows from the right-hand table.

Once you have a list of all of the Pupils with their corresponding sports (or `NULL` where there is no sport), then you can filter using the `WHERE` statement.  Remember that to indicate the `NULL` values, you will have to use something like `WHERE Sports IS NULL` instead of using the equality operator `=`.